# C# : Write/Read other executable file resource

Tags: c#, resources

Application **A** write some data into Executable **B** so Executable **B** can access this data

How to write/read resource to another executable.

Just a basic answer

I found a snippet of code to write resource to an application, and it's work but i can't retrive the data :

```
public class Packer : IDisposable
{
    private static byte[] MAGIC_NUMBER = { 0x44, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x6b, 0x4c, 0x75, 0x63 };

    private Stream inStream;

    public Packer(string filename, bool openReadonly = false)
    {
        inStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, openReadonly ? FileAccess.Read : FileAccess.ReadWrite, openReadonly ? FileShare.Read : FileShare.None);
    }

    public byte[] ReadData(int index)
    {
        byte[] mn_buf = new byte[MAGIC_NUMBER.Length];
        byte[] len_buf = new byte[sizeof(Int32)];
        int data_len = 0;
        inStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        for (int i = 0; i <= index; ++i)
        {
            inStream.Seek(-MAGIC_NUMBER.Length, SeekOrigin.Current);
            inStream.Read(mn_buf, 0, MAGIC_NUMBER.Length);
            inStream.Seek(-MAGIC_NUMBER.Length, SeekOrigin.Current);
            for (int j = 0; j < MAGIC_NUMBER.Length; ++j)
            {
                if (mn_buf[j] != MAGIC_NUMBER[j])
                {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Not enough data.");
                }
            }
            inStream.Seek(-sizeof(Int32), SeekOrigin.Current);
            inStream.Read(len_buf, 0, sizeof(Int32));
            inStream.Seek(-sizeof(Int32), SeekOrigin.Current);
            data_len = BitConverter.ToInt32(len_buf, 0);
            inStream.Seek(-data_len, SeekOrigin.Current);
        }
        byte[] data = new byte[data_len];
        inStream.Read(data, 0, data_len);
        return data;
    }

    public void AddData(byte[] data)
    {
        inStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        inStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        inStream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length), 0, sizeof(Int32));
        inStream.Write(MAGIC_NUMBER, 0, MAGIC_NUMBER.Length);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        inStream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

(I don't know how to narrow this down)

Thanks you !

Comment: Although your question is too broad, but just as a hint, the typical approach is to store the intermediate data (what is produced by A and should be used by B) in a shared storage and access it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can read resources from any assembly by

1. Obtain a reference to the assembly using Reflection
2. Pass the assembly as a constructor argument to a new `ResourceManager.`

Example:

```
var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("External.Resources.exe");
var manifests = asm.GetManifestResourceNames();

foreach (var s in manifests)
{
    var rm = new ResourceManager(s, asm);
    var rs = rm.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
    foreach (DictionaryEntry r in rs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Key: {0}\tValue:{1}", r, r.Key, r.Value); 
    }
}
```

Writing resources is a different matter. If a resource is included in an assembly, that means it has been compiled.  Unless your code is capable of compiling resources, it is not possible to inject resources into an external assembly.

You *could* compile the resources to a *third* file (with the `.resource.` extension) using [ResGen.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1(v=vs.110).aspx) (you'd have to spawn a separate process), but you would still need to compile the project to get the resources injected into the assembly.

If you are hell-bent on updating the original assembly, you could spawn a new process running  [ilasm.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with the `/resource` switch (which, in theory, will inject a .res file into an assembly).  You would need to set up a pretty complicated workflow to generate the .res file, get it into a compiled assembly, and replacing the original assembly, and if the assembly is signed then you will need the private key as well.